# Is it possible to do MS Dynamics 365 performance testing using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, microsoft-dynamics

Trying to create Web Performance Test script in Visual Studio for a Dynamics 365 application. But, Getting Unauthorised error while trying to run the script.

Was managed to get successful Login responnse for Microsoftlogin page.

And, Request "https://..XXx/G/AuthRedirect/Index.aspx" is getting response 
as below,
Login successful, loading application...
Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.

But, the next request to the actual CRM URL gets redirected back to login.microsoftonline.com/....

Comment: Some web site are challenging! You need to [edit] the question provide much more detail in your question about what is happening and what you expect.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to see learn about how to use this site. Also please read the excellent [help] pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [EasyRepro](https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro)?

This is an example which demonstrates how easy it is to do a basic test of navigating through Dynamics and opening a contact form:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.Dynamics365.UIAutomation.Api;
using Microsoft.Dynamics365.UIAutomation.Browser;
using System;
using System.Security;

namespace Microsoft.Dynamics365.UIAutomation.Sample
{
    [TestClass]
    public class OpenContact
    {
        private readonly SecureString _username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OnlineUsername"].ToSecureString();
        private readonly SecureString _password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OnlinePassword"].ToSecureString();
        private readonly Uri _xrmUri = new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OnlineCrmUrl"].ToString());

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestOpenActiveContact()
        {
            using (var xrmBrowser = new XrmBrowser(TestSettings.Options))
            {
                xrmBrowser.LoginPage.Login(_xrmUri, _username, _password);
                xrmBrowser.GuidedHelp.CloseGuidedHelp();

                var perf = xrmBrowser.PerformanceCenter;

                if (!perf.IsEnabled)
                    perf.IsEnabled = true;

                xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(500);
                xrmBrowser.Navigation.OpenSubArea("Sales", "Contacts");

                xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(2000);
                xrmBrowser.Grid.SwitchView("Active Contacts");

                xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(1000);
                xrmBrowser.Grid.OpenRecord(0);

            }
        }
    }
}
```